# File manipulation with Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell, file

I am trying to pick up Haskell!

But I feel like my code is a bit painful to write and read.

Do you have any pointers on how to improve its readability / style?

```
main = do
    contents <- fmap tail . fmap lines . readFile $ "testInput"
    let input = map pair_to_tuple .(map (map read)) . map words $ contents :: [(Int,Int)]
    let result = map (uncurry waffles) $ input
    let decorated_result = ["Case #" ++ show i ++ ": " ++ show s | (i,s) <- zip [1..length result] result] 
    writeFile "output.txt" $ unlines $ decorated_result

waffles row col = (row - 1)*(col - 1)

pair_to_tuple [a,b] = (a,b)
```

This script reads a file whose first line is a title, then every line is a couple of numbers. Then it drops the first line, and processes every pair of numbers using the function `waffles`, then it writes it back to an output file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
contents <- fmap tail . fmap lines . readFile $ "testInput"
```

can be written as

```
contents <- (tail . lines) <$> readFile "testInput"
```

Here we take advantage of the law `fmap f . fmap g == fmap (f . g)`. `<$>` is an infix version of `fmap`. `$` is extraneous here.

---

```
let input = map pair_to_tuple .(map (map read)) . map words $ contents :: [(Int,Int)]
```

can be written as

```
let input = map (pair_to_tuple . (map read) . words) contents :: [(Int,Int)]
```

For lists `map = fmap`, so `map f . map g == map (f . g)` also holds.

---

In

```
let result = map (uncurry waffles) $ input
```

the `$` sign is also extraneous.

---

```
let decorated_result = ["Case #" ++ show i ++ ": " ++ show s | (i,s) <- zip [1..length result] result]
```

You can exploit Haskell's lazy evaluation and create infinite list to zip with:

```
let decorated_result = ["Case #" ++ show i ++ ": " ++ show s | (i,s) <- zip [1..] result]
```

---

Otherwise I'd say the code is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your review! Why do you think I may have a typo on `[1..length result]`? The code certainly compiles and works as expected.

Comment: @Jsevillamol Oh, right, stupid me. Updated my answer.